# I inverted 2 GPIO pins. Is pi4 dead?

Tags: gpio, activity-led, act, restore

friends. I plugged in an LCD screen using single cables and accidently inverted the two top pins, numbers 1 and 2 as per the image reference. So 1 on the screen went into 2 from the Pi and vice versa. Now there's no ACT feedback at all. Is the Pi dead?

I tried flashing the SD card again and restoring EEPROM with a restoring image, but nothing happens.

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean "shorted" and not inverted. And yes, this is fatal for the PMIC (power management IC). Your Pi is dead.

Comment: Oh well! Thank you @kwasmich. I'm very new to hardware in general.

Comment: @kwasmich the OP said that the pins were `transposed`, not shorted